# Isabelle: Exporting "sqrt" to Haskell

Tags: haskell, code-generation, isabelle

Disclaimer: I'm a total Isabelle beginner.

I'm trying to export the "sqrt" function or rather functions and definitions using "sqrt" to Haskell. My first try was just:

```
theory Scratch
   imports Complex_Main
begin
   definition val :: "real" where "val = sqrt 4"

   export_code val in Haskell 
end
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
Wellsortedness error
(in code equation root ?n ?x ≡
              if equal_nat_inst.equal_nat ?n zero_nat_inst.zero_nat then zero_real_inst.zero_real
              else the_inv_into top_set_inst.top_set
                    (λy. times_real_inst.times_real (sgn_real_inst.sgn_real y)
                           (abs_real_inst.abs_real y ^ ?n))
                    ?x,
with dependency "val" -> "sqrt" -> "root"):
Type real not of sort {enum,equal}
No type arity real :: enum
```

So I tried to replace "sqrt" with Haskell's "Prelude.sqrt":

```
code_printing
  constant sqrt ⇀ (Haskell) "Prelude.sqrt _"

export_code val in Haskell
```

Which still resulted in the same error. Which seems rather odd to me, because replacing "plus" with some arbitrary function "f" seems to be fine:

```
definition val' :: "nat" where "val' = plus 49 1"

code_printing
  constant plus ⇀ (Haskell) "_ `f` _" 

export_code val' in Haskell
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about the `code_printing` issue, but what do you expect to happen here? `Wellsortedness error` during code generation usually means that what you're trying to export is simply not computable (or at least Isabelle doesn't know how).

What do you expect something like `sqrt 2` to compile to in Haskell? What about `sqrt pi`? You cannot hope to generate executable code for *all* real numbers. Isabelle's default implementation restricts itself to rational numbers.

Doing code-printing to replace Isabelle's `sqrt` with Haskell's `sqrt` is only going to give you a type error, since Haskell's `sqrt` works on floating point numbers, and not on Isabelle's exported `real` type.

There is a file in `~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Real_Approx_By_Float` that maps Isabelle's operations on real numbers to floating point approximations in Standard ML and OCaml, but this is for experimentation only, since you lose all correctness guarantees if you do that sort of thing.

Lastly, there is an entry in the *Archive of Formal Proofs* that provides exact executable [algebraic real numbers](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Algebraic_Numbers.html), so that you can do at least some operations with square root etc., but this is a big piece of work and the performance can be pretty bad in some cases.

There is also a `sqrt` operation on *natural* numbers in Isabelle (i.e. it rounds down) in `~~/src/HOL/Library/Discrete`, and that can easily be exported to Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

In the AFP there also is an entry `Sqrt_Babylonian`, which contains algorithms to compute sqrt up to a given precision epsilon > 0, without any floating point rounding errors.

Regarding the complexity of algebraic numbers that Manuel mentioned, it really depends on your input. If you use nested square-roots or combine different square-roots (like sqrt 2 + ... + sqrt 50), then the performance will degrade soonish. However, if you rarely use square-roots or always use the same square-root in multiple locations, then algebraic numbers might be fast enough.